# Is SPLFileObject atomic?

Tags: php, atomic

I'm wondering whether methods of PHPs SPLFileObject are atomic (e.g. thread-safe) or not?

If they aren't, I'll implement my own class, which will use `flock()`, but is this enough? Is the flock function really thread-safe? What if the collision occurs after I `fopen()` the file, but before I `flock()` it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misusing the term "thread-safe."  Thread saftey is (mostly) about shared resources in threaded code.  PHP doesn't have threading, and file handles aren't shared resources.  Files are shared resources, though.  I think you're looking for the term "[race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#File_systems)" instead.

> What if the collision occurs after I `fopen()` the file, but before I `flock()` it?

The same thing that would happen if you weren't using SPLFileObject.  Just make sure you never open+truncate, always open+append and then truncate once you have the lock.  This should be standard procedure if you're already aware of how file opening and locking race conditions work.